# How to plot live location with device map widget using ibm bluemix iot service?

Tags: watson-iot

I am Unable to populate Lat-Long fields in device map card, no update methods are suggested when tried to map values when device info card is selected as a source.

Answer (score 4):

The device map card reads the latitude and longitude values from events published to the Watson IoT Platform from the device in question.  The card needs to be configured to specify which properties on the event contain the  latitude and longitude values.  To do this, you need to:

1. Open the settings for the device map card
2. From the left hand navigation panel of the **Edit Device map Card** dialog, select **Device list**
3. In the content panel, you should see two entries, **Data point for longitude property** and **Data point for latitude property**.  Click on **Data point for longitude property** to expand it.
4. You are now able to specify the **Device type** and **Property** that contains the longitude value.
5. Repeat this process to define which property contains the latitude value.

**NOTE:** The **Device type** drop-down is only populated with device types that have a schema defined for them.  You can define a schema for a device type by navigating to **DEVICES** -> **Manage Schemas** and clicking the **Add Schema** button in the top right hand corner.